# ¿Como validar múltiples formularios con vuetify, vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

Buen día actualmente tengo 2 formularios.

Primer formulario:

```
<v-form @submit.prevent="iniciarSesion" ref="form" id="formLogin" lazy-validation>
                    <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" :rules="emailRules" name="login" label="Correo" type="text" v-model="email" required></v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field prepend-icon="lock" :rules="passwordRules" name="password" label="Contraseña" id="password" type="password" v-model="password" required></v-text-field>
                  </v-form>
```

dicho formulario al hacer uso de

```
this.$refs.form.validate()
```

se realiza la validacion

el problema que tengo es al querer utilizar un segundo formulario

```
<form @submit.prevent="completarRegistro" ref="formregistro" id="formRegistro" lazy-validation>
 </form>
```

ya que si realizo  `this.$refs.formregistro.validate()`, no realiza la validación.

me salta el siguiente mensaje: `"this.$refs.formregistro.validate is not a function"`
De antemano muy agradecido.

Comment: ¿Utilizas vee-validate?

Comment: No. Unicamente ref="form"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba colocando en las etiquetas

```
< v-form> < /v-form>
```

del segundo formulario.

Comment: haber ya va mejorando, ahora te pregunto, por que hacer ese cambio? por que esta propuesta soluciona el problema?